# Chrome Developer Tools SCSS Syncing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I add a workspace in chrome developer tools it links the css file I'm using but not the scss file it is generated from. No source map file is generated either. However when I compile the scssfile in netbeans a map file is saved to the css directory which chrome is able to read. I can then make changes to the scss file in the sources window and when I save it the page reloads with the recompiled css. So far so good.

The issue I'm having now is when I make live edits via the styles window in developer tools, the changes are not reflected in the scss file in the sources tab. This worked fine before when it was just linking to the css file.

Can anyone help me with this?